# Pandas replace not working even with inplace=True

Tags: pandas

I am using replace function, but it does not work. It is not doing the replacement,I still see original string. On the pandas documentation, the replace function does not even have an inplace argument, so I wonder if inplace actually works?

```
df["Name"].replace(["Bill"], "William", inplace=True)
```

I still see: Bill

Comment: `df["Name"]=df["Name"].str.replace("Bill", "William")` why is there a list in the name do you want a list to be replaced? if so can you please create a small df as example?

Comment: Why are you passing `['Bill']` as a list?

Comment: "On the pandas documentation, the replace function does not even have an inplace argument" - [yes, it does](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, passing your rename as a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bill','James','Joe','John','Bill'], 'Age': [34, 21, 34, 45, 23]})

df.replace({'Bill': 'William'}, inplace=True)

#OR

df['Name'].replace({'Bill': 'William'}, inplace=True)
```

Indeed, this produces:

```
      Name  Age
0  William   34
1    James   21
2      Joe   34
3     John   45
4  William   23
```